# SUBMIT ACTION (Adaptive Card - Bot Framework) not responding back after submit

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, form-submit, adaptive-cards

Im trying bot framewrok and practising adaptive cards. Got some YT tutorials also but stuck at one part even though I tried following the tutorial.

Problem:
When I try to submit my input, there's no confirmation or reply from the bot even though I put an action under data with messageBack.

What am I missing?
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHm6p.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF4VY.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqRuu.jpg)

I tried reviewing the tutorial and I checked that the process was right.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please share code, logs as TEXT in code blocks not as image. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using Bot Framework Emulator to test. In that, you can see the submitted activity back to the bot (select the correct message in the bottom-right pane). Trimmed down, you will notice that although the `type` is message; there is no `text` field. All the information is contained in the `value` field.

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "value": {
    "myColor2": "1"
  }
}
```

You will need to handle that appropriately (not sure what handlers you have implemented as you don't share any of that/code). More information or a snippet of your code will help.